# Awk or Sed: Replace text between special characters (delimiters)

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I do some research on how to replace text between delimiters, but because of lack knowledge in awk and sed I couldn't adjust command for my problem. The most similar question I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065948/1925060), but after adjusting command to `awk '/^(name=|&)/{f=f?0:1}f&&/*/{$0="//" $0}1' file` it didn't work. Also, I would like do replace using variable instead of doing replace in file. And if I didn't ask to much, very short explanation would be great :)

I have next url in variable `$url` and variable `$new=unnamed384`:

```
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4
```

I need to replace text between "name=" and "&" with variable `$new`.
E.g. This is variable `$url` before:

```
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4
```

This is variable `$url` after:

```
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed384&file=4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$ new="unnamed384"

$ url="http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4"

$ sed "s/name=[^&]*/name=$new/" <<< $url
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed384&file=4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've looked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/(.*\?name=)[^\&]*(&.*)/$1$n$2/g
```

The above will do.
tested below(used with perl)

```
> echo "http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4"
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4
> echo "http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4" | perl -lne '$n="unamed394";$_=~s/(.*\?name=)[^\&]*(&.*)/$1$n$2/g;print'
http://www.example.com/?name=unamed394&file=4
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new='unnamed384'; 
$echo 'http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed293&file=4' | awk -F'[=&]' '{ print $1"=""'"$new"'""&"$3"="$4 }'
http://www.example.com/?name=unnamed384&file=4
```